# how to record(copy) the kernal log messages in a Linux kernel system crash

Tags: linux-kernel, logs, kernel-panic

I enable logging to console by:

```
$ dmesg --console-level 7
$ dmesg --console-on
```

And I generated a system crash by:

```
$echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

I did get the crash stack trace in a Linux console (vitual console), as follows:

```
[    7.952685] sysrq: Trigger a crash
[    7.952850] Kernel panic - not syncing: sysrq triggered crash
[    7.953098] CPU: 0 PID: 71 Comm: linuxrc Not tainted 5.19.0-rc2 #1
[    7.953259] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS 1.14.0-2 04/01/2014
[    7.953655] Call Trace:
[    7.954133]  <TASK>
[    7.954332]  dump_stack_lvl+0x34/0x44
[    7.954651]  panic+0x102/0x27b
[    7.954756]  ? _printk+0x53/0x6a
[    7.954847]  sysrq_handle_crash+0x11/0x20
[    7.954953]  __handle_sysrq.cold+0x43/0x11b
[    7.955065]  write_sysrq_trigger+0x1f/0x30
[    7.955167]  proc_reg_write+0x4c/0x90
[    7.955267]  vfs_write+0xb4/0x290
[    7.955362]  ksys_write+0x5a/0xd0
[    7.955453]  do_syscall_64+0x3b/0x90
[    7.955553]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x46/0xb0
[    7.955773] RIP: 0033:0x4a8531
[    7.955999] Code: e0 ff ff ff f7 d8 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb b3 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 8b 05 d2 26 1e 00 85 c0 75 16 b8 01 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 57 c3 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 8
[    7.956427] RSP: 002b:00007ffde8168508 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000001
[    7.956625] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000000000101a8a0 RCX: 00000000004a8531
[    7.956787] RDX: 0000000000000002 RSI: 00000000010201e0 RDI: 0000000000000001
[    7.956949] RBP: 0000000000000001 R08: fefefefefefefeff R09: fefefefefefeff62
[    7.957113] R10: 00000000000001b6 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00000000010201e0
[    7.957275] R13: 0000000000000002 R14: 00007ffde8168701 R15: 00007ffde8168578
[    7.957467]  </TASK>
[    7.957806] Kernel Offset: 0x34a00000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[    7.958215] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: sysrq triggered crash ]---
```

While at the time, the Linux system crashed, and the keyboard was frozen, how am I supposed to copy the stack trace?

By the way, is there any other way to record the stack trace in cases of kernel panic? In   /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf, I disabled the cache (so always writing to disk) by:

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none /var/log/syslog*
```

But still, after reboot, I didn't find the logging message of the crash.

Answer (score 1):

For a VM, it's pretty easy.  Just add another serial console to the VM.  e.g. with libvirt, something like:

```
    <serial type='file'>
      <source path='/var/lib/libvirt/consoles/vm-name.log'/>
      <target type='isa-serial' port='1'>
        <model name='isa-serial'/>
      </target>
    </serial>
```

You'll also need the VM's kernel configured to use both the VM's virtual tty AND the serial port as the console.  e.g. in /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text console=tty0 console=ttyS1,115200n8"
```

Anything that goes to the console will be saved in the log file on the host machine...but note that it is over-written (not appended) every time the VM restarts.  You can, of course, rotate/mv/cp/etc the log file while the VM is down.

BTW, it's possible to have even more consoles configured - you could use a third one for serial console logins (either another virtual serial port or a real pass-through serial port).  You'd need to run a getty on that serial port in the VM, and connect to it with a terminal program like `minicom` running on the host machine (or a terminal/laptop/other machine connected via null-modem cable in the case of pass-through)..

For physical machines, it's harder.   If you have another machine nearby (that's always on), you could use a real serial port, connect the machines with a null-modem cable, and have the other machine constantly log whatever comes through on that serial port.   This is a fairly typical kernel debugging setup (or used to be, before almost everyone started using VMs instead).

Another possibility that **sometimes** works, but unreliably, is to configure your syslogd to remotely log kern.* messages to another machine.   Whether this works or not at any given instant depends on what, exactly, crashed in the kernel.  If the network is still up and a few syslog udp packets can get out, it'll be fine. Just look in the appropriate syslog files on the remote machine.

I have rsyslog on some of my machines configured to do this.  In particular, a pair of machines on my home network called `kali` (BTW, this is not running Kali Linux, it is running Debian...and has done so since the mid-90s, long before Kali Linux existed.  I was using Indian gods as my host naming scheme at the time.  Of course, both the hardware and the OS has been continuously upgraded many times since then.) and `ganesh` (also Debian) send their kern messages to each other.

ganesh has:

```
if $fromhost-ip == '127.0.0.1' and $syslogfacility-text == 'kern' then @kali
```

and kali has:

```
if $fromhost-ip == '127.0.0.1' and $syslogfacility-text == 'kern' then @ganesh
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a win10 PC running Putty connected to the Linux physical machine via USB to serial converter. And it works fine. Run getty on the ttyS1 on the Linux machine and log on via Putty on Win10. But is this a console or just an ordinary terminal? I tried sysrq but nothing output to the Putty.

Comment: sounds like it's just configured for login at the moment. you can either tell rsyslogd to send kern.* to ttyS1 (as well as wherever it's already sending it), or you can add one or more `console=` arguments to the kernel command line (as with grub above) - this won't take effect until you run `update-grub` and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer in stackoverflow.
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/72870750/10818184[How](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72870750/10818184%5BHow) to use decode_stacktrace.sh?][1]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer was flagged as low quality because it's essentially just a link elsewhere. While that target page may survive, it may not, so please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/referencing and follow the advice there. The fact that it's your own answer over on SO doesn't change the need to make *this* answer self-contained. Thank you!